# preg_replace variable replacement showing error with single quotes

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, double-quotes, single-quotes

I have this `preg_replace` statement,

```
$s = "Foo money bar";
echo preg_replace("/(office|rank|money)/i", "<strong>$1</strong>", $s);
```

Which returns,

```
Foo <strong>money</strong> bar
```

However when I try doing the exact same thing with single quotes and with a function being used on `$i` it breaks,

```
$s = "Foo money bar";
echo preg_replace("/(office|rank|money)/i", '<strong>' . ucfirst($1) . '</strong>', $s);
```

Note the single quotes in the second parameter of the function, this now yields,

```
syntax error, unexpected '1' (T_LNUMBER), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'
```

**Live Example**

[Double Quotes](https://repl.it/Ktg9/3)

[Single Quotes](https://repl.it/Ktg9/2)

So my question is why does this occur and how could I get the expected output (strong with `ucfirst`) as shown in the second example?

### Update #1

This issue is happening not only because of the function `ucfirst` but due to the single quotes too as can be seen in [this](https://repl.it/Ktg9/4) example,

```
$s = "Foo money bar";
echo preg_replace("/(office|rank|money)/i", '<strong>' . $1 . '</strong>', $s);
```

**Output**

```
syntax error, unexpected '1' (T_LNUMBER), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a function in the second parameter of `preg_replace`.
 `'<strong>' . ucfirst($1) . '</strong>'` is evaluated before the search. To use a function in a regex replacement, you have to use preg_replace_callback:

```
$result = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($m) {
    return '<strong>' . ucfirst($m[1]) . '</strong>';
}, $yourstring);
```

Comment: Could you explain the single quotes issue then? Even if I remove the function it still won't work.

Comment: @Script47: this isn't related to single or double quotes. This is related to the use of a function in the second parameter of `preg_replace`.

Comment: It most definitely is to do with the single quotes too, check [this](https://repl.it/Ktg9/4).

Comment: @Script47: I already explain what is the problem, but sorry I can't understand for you. If something is unclear in my answer, feel free to ask.

Comment: Please check the link in my above comment, the function usage has been removed and it still doesn't work when I am using single quotes.

Comment: @Script47: One more time, nothing to do with quotes: `$1` isn't a variable, it's a placeholder for a capture group.

Comment: Have you checked the example I provided?

Comment: Please see @ishegg's answer, essentially that is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting that error not because of the type of quotes, but because you're doing it outside the quotes.

```
echo preg_replace("/(office|rank|money)/i", "<strong>" . $1 . "</strong>", $s);
```

This throws the same error. That's because **`$1` is not a variable**, it's a [back reference](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.back-references.php). You can refer to it as `\1` instead of `$1` and it'll be clearer.

So, you can't refer to the back reference outside the quotes (besides, `$1` would be an illegal variable name). I can't refer to the specific internals on how this works (couldn't find anything), but it probably is set as a "flag" for the interpreter to replace with the nth matching group.

Interestingly, if you use a function as the second parameter *and* wrap the back reference in quotes, it still works! (In the sense that it won't error out. It still won't run the function.)

```
<?php
$s = "Foo money bar";
echo preg_replace("/(office|rank|money)/i", '<strong>' . ucfirst('$1') . '</strong>', $s); // works with single and double quotes
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/ZTdpU)

[This article](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html) doesn't talk about this but it's a great read anyway.

Comment: Notice that `ucfirst` isn't actually being called on the variable.

Comment: Yeah, I’d added a clarification: “it works in the sense that it won’t error out. It still won’t run the function.”

Comment: Any ideas how it could be used to make the function call work or for that matter why the function call doesn't work?

Comment: It’s because the second parameter isn’t interpreted by PHP but by the regex engine. You used to be able to add the `e` modifier to `eval()` the second parameter, but it’s deprecated now. Your only option really is using `preg_replace_callback()` instead.